# javascript to calculate simple multiplication automatically upon changing any number

Tags: javascript

I'm not a javascript programmer, but I have to use it for a calculation I need to do on a wordpress page.

Here is what I need:

- 3 fields in html where I can enter a number (a form).
- a text field where the multiplication is "printed"
- if I change one element, a new result must apear, without me needing to push any button.

any idea on how to do this? 
I know how to do the calculation as such, but not that it works automatically.

HEre is what I got so far:

```
    <html>

<head>

<title>Simple Javascript Calculator - Basic Arithmetic Operations</title>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function multiply(){
    a=Number(document.calculator.number1.value);
    b=Number(document.calculator.number2.value);
    c=a*b;
    document.calculator.total.value=c;
}
</script>



</head>

<body>

<!-- Opening a HTML Form. --> 
<form name="calculator">

<!-- Here user will enter 1st number. --> 
Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1"> 


<!-- Here user will enter 2nd number. --> 
Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2"> 


<!-- Here result will be displayed. --> 
Get Result: <input type="text" name="total"> 


<!-- Here respective button when clicked, calls only respective artimetic function. --> 
<<input type="button" value="MUL" onclick="javascript:multiply();">


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: Show us first what you tried, for example in a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com).

Comment: Have you considered checking out calculator plugins for wordpress? I'm pretty sure you will bump into something that does what you want

Comment: @dystroy I pasted my code so far.

Comment: And how would the calculator know which action should be performed? Or is it only multiplication?

Comment: @Bart: That's the tough part :D

Comment: the function does not matter... what I need is to know how to run this function at any time the user changes a number... and when the page loads for the first time. So that there is no need for the button.

Comment: your calling the function with your button, if you want to call it when a value is changed, put it on the text inputs onchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ***<kbd>[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/2yTLp/)</kbd>***

You are going to be forced to use an interval if you want to monitor two inputs and handle all changes (such as pasting in, either from a mouse, from ctrl+v, from using the edit+paste browser input, from typing, etc.).

If you do not need to handle all cases, then onkeyup will work as Bart suggests. Here is an interval approach:

```
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var y = document.getElementById("y");
var d = document.getElementById("d");
var xstored = x.getAttribute("data-in");
var ystored = y.getAttribute("data-in");
setInterval(function(){
 if( x == document.activeElement ){
  var temp = x.value;
  if( xstored != temp ){
   xstored = temp;
   x.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
   calculate();
  }
 }
 if( y == document.activeElement ){
  var temp = y.value;
  if( ystored != temp ){
   ystored = temp;
   y.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
   calculate();
  }
 }
},50);

function calculate(){
 d.innerHTML = x.value * y.value;
}
x.onblur = calculate;
calculate();
```

Comment: I think I'm using this solution. It's better. I could not make bart's aproach work for more than 1 variables. Thanks

Comment: look at the final result: http://www.green-and-energy.com/de/fuelspy/ (is in german, but does not matter)

Answer (score 1):

This will not answer the problem for your specific question but a nice way to do your calculations is through the `eval` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/gL3YF/1/

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="expression" value="1 + 1" />
<hr />
<h3 id="result"></h3>
```

The Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('expression');
input.onkeyup = function () {
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerHTML = eval(this.value);
};

//evaluate initial value
input.onkeyup();
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! not explicitly, but I can use your example. many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use the `onchange` event on each `input` element so that when a user changes `input[value]` an operation is triggered. You should also cache the previously performed operation so that it's applied to the operands when onchange event is triggered

Comment: this was my recommendation above

Comment: It's similar but I'm disagreeing with `eval`. Should you be really recommending it?

Comment: `eval` is just as safe as any other javascript code as long as you don't evaluate input from untrusted sources. In this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: It might not matter in this case but I would rather be paranoid and stay away from the damn thing. Eval screwed me over once so I hardly recommend it